# Javascript not executed after using window.location.hash

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to redirect the user to another page, I have used window.location.hash = "../pagePath.html"; but it does redirect to the page without firing the JavaScript code, is some jQuery Mobile solution for this? something like "ajax-false" that I can use in JS code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use

```
window.location.href="../pagePath.html";
```

whereas

```
window.location.hash
```

will return the anchor value from the url.
for Ex.: your browser url is www.google.com/accounts#gmail
then if you get the window.location.hash like this

```
var anc=window.location.hash;
```

then and will return "gmail".